# Losing 6 bytes but only if socket goes quiet for 60 seconds?

Tags: php, sockets, curl, chunked-encoding

I've been running two socket clients side-by-side, collecting http streaming data (not Twitter, but similar kind of thing). The data comes through in chunked encoding.

One of the clients is curl (on the commandline, not php-curl), where both http and https work fine. The other is my own PHP script, using `fsockopen` and `fgets`. Works fine for https, but I have a specific problem with http. How specific? It only happens if the stream goes quiet for 60 seconds. If there is only 50 seconds of quiet it works fine. I've been comparing curl's http headers sent and received to my script, and have removed all differences. I thought I knew everything there was to know about PHP sockets, and especially chunked encoding, but it is time to eat humble pie as this one has me stumped.

So, running curl with "--trace - --trace-time", I see this come through for the first packet after the 60 second quiet period:

```
05:56:57.025023 <= Recv data, 136 bytes (0x88)
0000: 38 32 0d 0a 7b 22 64 61 74 61 66 65 65 64 22 3a 82..{"datafeed":
0010: 22 64 65 6d 6f 2e 31 64 36 2e 31 6d 2e 72 61 6e "demo.1d6.1m.ran
...
0080: 34 22 7d 5d 7d 0a 0d 0a                         4"}]}...
```

The 82 is hex for size of the chunk. The \r\n marks the end of the chunk size line. The chunk starts at the "{".

Over on the PHP side, my loop starts like this:

```
while(true){
  if(feof($fp)){fclose($fp);return "Remote server has closed\n";}
  $chunk_info=trim(fgets($fp)); //First line is hex digits giving us the length
  $len=hexdec($chunk_info);   //$len includes the \r\n at the end of the chunk (despite what wikipedia says)
```

With https, or with a less than 60 second gap, this works fine, $len is 100 or whatever the chunk size is.
But, after that 60 second gap, what I get in $chunk_info is:

```
datafeed":"demo.1d6.1m.ran...
```

So, I seem to have lost the first six bytes: `38 32 0d 0a 7b 22`

All subsequent chunks are fine, and exactly the same as what curl is receiving.

---

**Version Details**

curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:12:47)

Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

(I've only tested with localhost connections so far.)

---

The rest of the loop looks like this:

```
$s='';
$len+=2;    //For the \r\n at the end of the chunk
while(!feof($fp)){
    $s.=fread($fp,$len-strlen($s));
    if(strlen($s)>=$len)break;  //TODO: Can never be >$len, only ==$len??
    }
$s=substr($s,0,-2);
if(!$s)continue;
$d=json_decode($s);
//Do something with $d here
}
```

(Aside: in the way I've tested so far, the code has passed through this loop exactly once, before the 60 second quiet period.)

---

NOTE: I have numerous workarounds to get things working: e.g. enforce use of https, or use curl-php. This question is because I want to know what is going on, know what is changing after 60 seconds, and learn how to stop it happening. And maybe learn a new troubleshooting idea. Think of it as bloody-minded intellectual curiosity :-)

Comment: Of curiosity: why didn't you start with PHP's cURL?

Comment: Can we see the rest of your loop, especially the part that consumes the socket's buffer?

Comment: @FrancisAvila Thanks for the interest, just posted it.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I didn't want the curl dependency unless there was really no alternative. And this code should work - it has run for hundreds of hours, if not more, but only with streams that never went quiet for that long! And it still works perfectly with https.

Comment: Can you pull out tcpdump or Ethereal and see if what's actually coming over the wire agrees with what curl's dumping?  You mentioned that all of this is local so far.  Have you tried going over your local network, to another device?  Assuming there are other devices to check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bug fix:

```
$chunk_info=trim(fgets($fp)); //First line is hex digits giving us the length
if($chunk_info=='')continue; //Usually means the default 60 second time-out on fgets() was reached.
...
```

If fgets($fp) returns *something* then you have a chunk to read. If that something is a zero then you have a blank chunk to process. But when it returns *nothing* it means fgets has timed-out. It appears the default time-out for tcp:// is 60 seconds; whereas the default time-out for ssl:// is longer (sorry, I've not tracked down what it is yet - it may be that it blocks forever).

By trying to process a chunk when there was none to read, everything got out of sync. Hence the stolen 6 bytes.

Troubleshooting tips:

1. Litter the code with: `echo "**".date("Y-m-d H:i:s");print_r(stream_get_meta_data($fp));ob_flush();flush();` The meta data has an entry to say when the last stream action had a time-out. Datestamp is essential.
2. Cross-reference with `tcpdump -A -i lo port http` from the commandline. Compare timestamps with those from the debug lines in PHP, allowed me to spot suspicious behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why your code behaves that way, but the way it reads data is not correct; I would rewrite it to something like this:

```
$chunkmeta = fgets($f);
// chunked transfer can have extensions (indicated by semi-colon)
// see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html
$chunklen = hexdec(current(explode(';', $chunkmeta, 2)));

// chunk length is non-zero
if ($chunklen) {
  $chunk = '';
  // only read up to chunk length
  while (!feof($f) && $chunklen) {
      if ($buf = fread($f, $chunklen)) {
          $chunklen -= strlen($buf);
          $chunk .= $buf;
      } else {
          // uh oh, something bad happened
          die("Could not read chunk");
      }
  }
  if ($chunklen == 0) {
      // read the trailing CRLF
      fread($f, 2); // read CRLF
      // data is ready
  }
}
```

**Update**

Should have gone with my gut instinct on this one (though above code should work just fine either way); the [`default_socket_timeout`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) setting is 60 seconds by default, so any subsequent reads should return `false`. Still doesn't explain why it would work on secure sockets ;-)

Comment: BTW, do you know any web servers that use ";", or is this just to be future-proof? AFAIK Apache has never sent me one.

Comment: Great code, Jack, and I (now!) see it does not have the bug I had.

Comment: I've never seen chunk extensions being used, but the syntax is described [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html)